# Django Twoscoops and SECRET_KEY generation

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am trying to follow the django twoscoops best practices. In [settings/base.py](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/project_name/settings/base.py), there is the following:

```
########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
# Note: This key should only be used for development and testing.
SECRET_KEY = r"{{ secret_key }}"
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION
```

How is this working? Is it generating a random secret key all by itself? Is it constantly changing values, and is this a problem everytime I reinstall django into my new production environment? Will it generate a new, secure secret key once I push it to a production server, or is it like the note says, that the key generated is not safe to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a project template. It is populated when you do `django-admin.py startproject`.

In fact, this isn't even specific to Two Scoops: the [Django code itself](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py) does exactly the same thing.